# Can't Install VLC In Ubuntu 16.04 [ERROR]

Tags: apt, 16.04, vlc

I am using Ubuntu 16.04. I am a new user want to learn terminal.  I prefer using the terminal instead of Software Center. I tried several times to install `vlc` by using both:

```
$ sudo apt-get update    
$ sudo apt-get install vlc browser-plugin-vlc
```

and

```
$ sudo apt-get update    
$ sudo apt-get install vlc browser-plugin-vlc
```

But this message appears every time:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 vlc : Depends: vlc-nox (= 3.0.0~~git20160525+r64784+62~ubuntu16.10.1) but 2.2.4-4 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

So, at last against my will I went to Software Center. However, to install `vlc` I had to log in at Ubuntu One. I tried to log in, but I can't. It said `invalid email/password`.

So, tell me what can I do, please?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the outputs of `apt policy vlc vlc-nox` and `grep -r --include "*.list" "^deb" /etc/apt/sources.list*`. You have a version conflict because you probably have an unofficial software source added that provides newer versions of `vlc`, but not its dependency `vlc-nox`.

Comment: He's got a vlc from the vlc master ppa  for 16.10 built on 05/25 & probably isn't using 16.04 as 2.2.4-4 is the ubuntu repo vlc version for 16.10. (or has mixed in 16.10 repos on a 16.04 install

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short answer**: You're trying to install `vlc` in version 3.0.0, but the `vlc` package depends on `vlc-nox` (and maybe others). `apt` can't find a `vlc-nox` package in version 3.0.0 in the repositories you configured, only one in version 2.2.4. Also, you're trying to install a `vlc` package meant for Ubuntu 16.10 on Ubuntu 16.04, which may cause problems.

**Long answer**: Packages can depend on other packages. To install `vlc`, you need to install `vlc-nox` (VLC to use without a graphical interface, "no X") as well in a corresponding version. If you, for example, want to install `vlc` in version 2.2.0, you need `vlc-nox` in version 2.2.0.

`apt` tries to install the latest version of a package it can get from the repositories you have configured. In your case, that is `vlc 3.0.0~~git20160525+r64784+62~ubuntu16.10.1`. So you would need a 3.0.0 version of `vlc-nox` as well. But the latest version of `vlc-nox` that's available from your repositories is `2.2.4-4`.

Also, the `3.0.0~~git20160525+r64784+62~ubuntu16.10.1` version is meant for Ubuntu 16.10, not Ubuntu 16.04. It's always a gamble to use packages that were build for different Ubuntu versions. It may work, it may not work.

So you need to check the repositories you have installed. There might be a repository that's meant for a later Ubuntu version and doesn't work on your version.